# How to remove the page error when Streamlit loads from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, bokeh, streamlit

I have a Streamlit page which works perfectly and connects to Pandas dataframe behind the scene. However, I get the following error till an excel file is imported into Streamlit. I saw a post suggesting to used the bold code below in asterix but issue is then rest of my code which includes sorting and grouping dataframe and then bokeh plot fails to recognize the dataframe because all the code needs to be indented due to "If" below.

```
dataset = st.file_uploader("upload file here", type = ['csv'])
***if dataset is not None:***
        df = pd.read_csv(dataset)
        st.write('## Data set')
```

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please give me a lead?

Comment: You only permitted files with the ending csv (type = 'csv') but excel files can also have a .xlsx ending. Maybe that's the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code in a try-except block as follows:

```
try:
   dataset = st.file_uploader("upload file here", type = ['csv'])
   if dataset is not None:
        df = pd.read_csv(dataset)
        st.write('## Data set')
except:
    st.write("Please load a file to continue...")
```

This solved the issue for me. Cheers